# ASP.NET binding second result set

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

I would like to bind text to my button from my second result set. Normally I do that using below code

```
Text='<%# Bind("StaffCount") %>'
```

I would like to do something like `Text='<%# Bind("secondResult.ColumnName") %>'`

EDIT
Thank You for Your replies. My question is how/where should I bind the second query result to get acces to it? I have a childgridview where I am binding the first query result. I have also footer where I have button to which I want assign Text='<%# Bind("StaffCount") %>'

Comment: second result set??? I think you have only one datasource to bind/

Comment: I have stored procedure which returns two results. I used AllStaffInfo.DataSource = GetStaff(cityID, gvoTeamID).Tables[0]; to bind Text='<%# Bind("StaffCount") %>'. Now I want to bind second result set (which is only one cell) to button's text.

Comment: My suggestion is to flatten the second result set into the first, either through merging the data tables in the data set or by creating a view in your database and having your data-access code retrieve the data from a view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have said in your comment

```
AllStaffInfo.DataSource = GetStaff(cityID, gvoTeamID).Tables[0];
```

This is used as datasource. So Here you are using `Tables[0]` i.e. first table as Data Source.

And your second Table contains only single column then I think you can include that column in first table itself. As you always have only one data source to bind `AllStaffInfo`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple result sets (read: data tables) in a data set, then you can merge each of the data tables into a single data table that could then be bound to the UI control, like this:

```
DataTable dtFinal = new DataTable();

ds.Tables[0]. Merge(ds.Tables[1]);
ds.Tables[0]. Merge(ds.Tables[2]);

dtFinal = ds.Tables[0];
```

If naming collisions may occur between merging data tables, then another alternative is to have your stored procedure return a view with appropriately named columns.